# Check/display the declared type of an entity (variable, expression...)

Tags: vba, types, vb6, vbscript

I am investigating types in VB especially in VBA. Generally, given an entity there are two types: `Effective value type`, I guess, is defined as `value types` in [this part of the specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324%28prot.20%29.aspx); `Declared Type` is defined in [this part of the specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199764%28prot.20%29.aspx).

To do tests, I need to use some functions to check types. There are [TypeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278698.aspx) and [VarType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278470.aspx). I think they are used to check `effective value type` of an entity, because `TypeName` can return `DBNull`, `Decimal` and `Nothing`; `VarType` can return `vbNull`, `vbEmpty`, `vbError` and `vbDecimal`. These types exist in the table of `effective value types`, but not in the table of `declared type`.

So now, my question is, does anyone know how to check/display the `declared type` of an entity (variable, expression...)?

**Edit 1:** Probably for a variable, its `declared type` is just the type that the declaration of the variable specifies. I would like to insist that, it seems that VBA has `declared type` for expressions. For instance, `Operator Declared Type` is mentioned in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177477%28prot.20%29.aspx). I think that refers to the `declared type` of the result of an operation. That means such entities as `-i`, `i+5`, `i>6`... can have a `declared type`. I would like to know how to display their declared type.

Comment: `TypeName` and `VarType` are regular function with a single `Variant` parameter, so no matter "declared type" every variable is cast to `Variant` before passing to them. In this `VarType(1)` what is the "declared type" of 1? It's not a variable, so it's not declared/dimensioned at all. The only way to implement something like this is through a special language construct, not a function, and I'm not aware of any, closest being `TypeOf ... Is`

Comment: It seems that `TypeOf` can only checks `Object` in VBA, we cannot use it to check `Interger`, `String`...

Comment: VarType in VBA & VBScript is not the same as the reference you link, it is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfz157h(v=vs.84).aspx, and does what you want, I think.

Comment: @Remou, I think your link and [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/vartype-function-HA001228932.aspx) are both valid for VBA. But the types it checks are `effective value type`, instead of `declared type` I think...

Comment: If you try this: `Dim i As Integer: Debug.Print VarType(i) = vbInteger` You will see it returns True, that is, a check of the declared type, yesno?

Comment: None of the forms of VB under discussion ever "cast" anything.  They _convert_ which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: @Remou, indeed it returns True, but isn't it just because the `effective value type` of (the default value of) `i` is `Integer`?

Comment: This is the correct reference for `TypeName` in VBA - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278698.aspx The link in the question is for VB

Comment: `i` is an integer because its declared as an integer, within the scope of that declaration `i` is forever & always an integer. The only context where the phrase "effective value type" has meaning is when a variant holds a value, are you asking how to determine the corresponding datatype for the value in a variant?

Comment: @barrowc, you are right. I just replaced the link in OP by your link...

Comment: @AlexK. `Operator Declared Type` is mentioned in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177477(prot.20).aspx). I think that refers to the `declared type` of the result of an operation. That means besides declared variable, other entities (e.g. `-i`, `i+5`, `i>6`...) can have a `declared type`. I would like to know how to display their `declared type`.

Comment: @Beaner, for assignment, there are also semantics for Let-coercion: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199374(prot.20).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156921(prot.20).aspx) which are applied. But still, I don't think you understand my question about `declared type`, instead of `effective value type`.

Comment: Well typename does that as well no? `typename(i+5) == int` / `typename(i+32768) == long` / `typename(i + 9999999999) == double`

Comment: @AlexK. I believe `TypeName` returns their `effective value type`, instead of `declared type` here...

Answer (score 1):

If,

```
Dim i as integer
i = 6/3
```

then you do,     `TypeName(i>3)` 
it returns **Boolean** which is the expression's *Type* based on the Type of the resulting value it holds not operand's declare type. And it complies with the specification given in your link for [msdn 2.2 Entities and Declared Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199764%28prot.20%29.aspx).

Or else are you looking for a syntax/function (e.g. DType, imaginative function) that could return DType(i>3) as integer which is operand's (i) Type? Or rather it's more useful when you have multiple variables within some expression, so you can find all their Types in one go?
*e.g. some String that combined all sorts of different TYPE variables in one expressoin.*

Just trying to **understand when and how this can be useful** to you and what could be the end result you are looking for.. Seems like this is more to lanague root definitions.

*PS: I do not have reps points to comment. So I added as an answer.*